# Google App Script LDAP Access Control

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to restrict access to an application built on Google App Script using LDAP? Can Google App Script access LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to look at this problem.

1. Apps Script cannot directly access your LDAP system. Apps Script has ability make HTTP calls to REST/SOAP services, make JDBC calls to external databases but it doesn't have built in support for the LDAP directory.
2. However, if you are using Apps Script w/in a Google Apps domain then you can tie in Google user accounts to LDAP using [Google Apps Directory Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106368). Once this is setup, you can deploy your Apps Script to only allow people w/in your domain and Google will make them login before they can access the Apps Script.

Hope this helps.