# LDAP Search from Google Apps Script (ideally within Sheets)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ldap

I see that there's a somewhat-similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737168/google-app-script-ldap-access-control), but it's 8 years old, so I thought I might ask again:

Is there any way to do an LDAP search from within a Google Apps Script (like ldapsearch on the command line, or an ldaps call)? Even better would be if that script could run within Google Sheets.

My hope is that I might be able to take a column of email addresses in a Sheet and fill in subsequent columns with details from our LDAP server. I know I could do it from python connecting to both Sheets and LDAP, but I'm hoping to implement something a bit more user-friendly for the nontechnical folks that would find that useful. I also know that I can do RESTful https calls from Google Apps Script, but I haven't found a way to do ldaps calls.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is not any native Apps Script LDAP service

You could always make a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) if you think its significant.

#### Workaround

You could write a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=en) within Apps Script to wrap your HTTP requests, and so, abstracting the request to a level more suited to your users.

Then you could just tell your users to add your library and provide some instructions on how to use your classes or functions.

Comment: Thanks @iansedano! I realize I wasn't clear--while I know how to do https calls from Apps Script, in this case I need LDAPS, as there aren't https endpoints available that will give me what I need. I've created the feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181593640 -- upvotes appreciated!